# My contact form is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

my contact form in my responsive website is not submitting. i have attached my contact.php but it is not working

my script is as follows

```
<!--Contact Us Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    $(function() {
        $('#contactform').submit(function() {                 
            var action = $(this).attr('action');

            $.post(action, { 
                name: $('#name').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                company: $('#website').val(),
                subject: $('#subject').val(),
                message: $('#message').val()
            },

            function(data) {
                $('#contactform #submit').attr('disabled','');
                $('.response').remove();
                $('#contactform').before('<p class="response">'+data+'</p>');
                $('.response').slideDown();

                if(data=='Message sent!') $('#contactform').slideUp();
            }
        ); 

        return false;
    });
});
```

and my actual form is

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contactform">
    <ol>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Name*</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" class="text"/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email">Email*</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" class="text" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="url">Website</label>
            <input id="url" name="web" class="text"/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="subject">Subject*</label>
            <input id="subject" name="subject" class="text"/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="message">Message*</label>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="6" cols="50" ></textarea>
        </li>
        <li class="buttons">
            <input name="imageField" type="image" class="send" id="imageField"      form="contactform" src="Newsite/images/sub.png" />
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</form>
```

I would be really grateful if someone could assist. I've been stuck for 2 days now!!!

Thanks

Comment: any js errors on console?

Comment: Sidenote: 2 days? I wouldn't have lost 2 hours, yet alone 2 "minutes" in trying to make this work. I'd of just found a working script and got on with my life. Unless... unless you built it from scratch and don't want your baby to die, now that's a different story. ;-) (Btw, you have a missing closing `</script>` tag in your code. If that's what you're actually using without it... add it.

Comment: sorry i'm just starting out with building a site so don't really no what I'm doing

Comment: A // <![CDATA[ wrapper is not required.

Comment: Sorry? No need to be sorry. I suggest you find a working example and study it, then modify it to suit your needs (coding needs that is), all with a "copy" and not the original working copy that can be found on the Web. You can't be expected to know something, unless you've examined a working example. No one is born with JS/HTML/PHP etc. embedded in our DNA at birth ;-)

Comment: @Diodeus - not only is it not required, but it's also not closed.   :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it... Attach the function, to the event "click" from the img...
Sorry, (i can't speak(wirte or listen) english so much) but I hope it will help.

```
$("#imageField").click(
   function(){
   $('#contactform').submit(function(){                  
      var action = $(this).attr('action');
      $.post(action, { 
          name: $('#name').val(),
          email: $('#email').val(),
          company: $('#website').val(),
          subject: $('#subject').val(),
          message: $('#message').val()
    },
   function(data){
       $('#contactform #submit').attr('disabled','');
       $('.response').remove();
       $('#contactform').before('<p class="response">'+data+'</p>');
       $('.response').slideDown();
       if(data=='Message sent!') $('#contactform').slideUp();
   }
 );
 return false;
 });
```